# Does Nand Flash Type Affect the Read Latency Based on Page Content?

Tags: computer-architecture, storage

In general, we have these types of NAND flash cells: SLC, MLC, TLC, and QLC. Since MLC flash cells can store 2 bits, the content of the cell can be 00, 01, 10, or 11 which are detected using different threshold voltages. Each 4KB flash page includes 32768 bits and, thus, 16384 MLCs. So, the content of a page might be all 1, all 0, or a mixture of 1 and 0. Are these types of page content read with different latencies or not? Is there a distinguishable read latency between the pages containing all 1, all 0, and a mixture of 1 and 0?